# IBM / Lenovo APS with Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lenovo-laptop

I was wondering if anyone has intergrated the IBM / Lenovo APS for Hard Drives into the linux kernel or as a package.

APS is the Active Protection System which suspends drive writes in the event of a sudden jolt of energy from an impact or movement.

All of the stuff I have found ends around 2005 with a project on sourceforge.

Does that mean its a dead end or has it been added to the upstream kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to exists even two versions, one in the kernel and one in a software/project called "tp_smapi": http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/HDAPS#Harddisk_Protection

Comment: Hmm based on that it still seems like it might be a better idea to just run Windows on the notebook and virtualize Linux, that way I get the Lenovo power management plus the APS software. Thanks for the help.